# (intermediate value) is not a function when running anonymous async iify in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, asynchronous, async-await

Sorry this might seem like a stupid question but I have no idea why it's throwing this error, this is the entire code in an index.js file that I try to run!

```js
(async() => {
  console.log('hi');
})();
```

And it returns this error!

```
(intermediate value) is not a function`
```

When I turn into a regular async function and call it it works fine.

Comment: What is the line above your `(async () => {`? Sounds almost certain to be an ASI issue

Comment: @CertainPerformance wow I added a semi colon to the function above and it fixed it. A collegue recently told me that you  pretty much don't have add to semi colons but clearly that's wrong.

Comment: Definitely wrong. Unless you're an expert and can avoid the pitfalls of ASI on sight, use semicolons, else you'll occasionally run into weird bugs like these.

Comment: Cheers thanks!! I'll read about ASI